# VSTS Package Management: Missing NuGet package icons in own package feed

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, nuget, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I'm in the progress of migrating a private NuGet gallery from an Azure App Service to a VSTS Package Management feed. I pushed all nupkg files to this feed, and am able to consume this feed with Visual Studio, but now all packages show the NuGet default icon.

I've checked the feed output with Fiddler: The resulting JSON document contains "iconUrl" properties with the correct URLs but for some reason, they don't show up in the NuGet Package Manager.

Does anybody know how to fix this? Is this an issue with the feed (not returning a correct JSON response) or with the NuGet Package Manager?

Answer (score 1):

Our current design doesn't send back image URLs. I'll get it on our backlog to support in the future.

Comment: Any news or page where we can follow evolution of this feature? I have the same issue as @C.Sura. any date for a fix?

Comment: It looks like this shipped recently. Are you still not seeing the images? I'm no longer on the direct team involved, so I will have someone from that team weigh in here.

Comment: Hi, thx for the feedback. Yes I'm still experiencing the issue. I'm on VSTS with a fresh started feed and packages created with the Package Management VSTS extension a week ago.

Comment: Ok I've emailed the PMs who own that area and pointed them to this thread.

Comment: This is still on the backlog, unfortunately. If you'd like, help us prioritize the work by upvoting this on our UserVoice: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/16274398-show-icons-for-packages-in-the-visual-studio-nuget

Comment: I need this :-/

Comment: In 2020 this still does not work. DevOps is missing delivering other meta infos like tags too.

Comment: Updated UserVoice link https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/show-icons-for-packages-in-the-visual-studio-nuget/365589